# Compare Dates Between A Range in DataFrame and Join Matches

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reconcile events that would alter a customer's invoice between very specific time periods. I am half-tempted to load this data into a couple of local MySQL tables, but am curious how to solve the problem specifically in `pandas`.

Here's some fake data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'user_id':['123','456','789','333'],
    'first_invoice_date':['2017-10-01','2017-03-01','2017-02-01','2017-08-01'],
    'third_invoice_date':['2017-12-31','2017-05-31','2017-04-30','2017-10-31']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['user_id','first_invoice_date','third_invoice_date'])

events = {
    'user_id':['123','123','456','789','789','101'],
    'event_type':['downgrade','cancel','refund','downgrade','cancel','discount],
    'event_date':['2017-11-15','2017-12-08','2017-01-23','2017-02-15','2017-02-28','2017-04-05']
}
event_df = pd.DataFrame(events,columns=['user_id','event_type','event_date'])

df['first_invoice_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_invoice_date'])
df['third_invoice_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['third_invoice_date'])
event_df['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(event_df['event_date'])
```

The example data produces the following dataframes:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
  user_id first_invoice_date third_invoice_date
0     123         2017-10-01         2017-12-31
1     456         2017-03-01         2017-05-31
2     789         2017-02-01         2017-04-30
3     333         2017-08-01         2017-10-31

In [3]: event_df
Out[3]:
  user_id event_type  event_date
0     123  downgrade  2017-11-15
1     123     cancel  2017-12-08
2     456     refund  2017-01-23
3     789  downgrade  2017-02-15
4     789     cancel  2017-02-28
5     101   discount  2017-04-05
```

What I want is if an event 1) matches the `user_id` and 2) is between the `invoice` dates in `df`, I would like to concatenate the first such event to `df`, which would result in this:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
  user_id first_invoice_date third_invoice_date  event_type  event_date
0     123         2017-10-01         2017-12-31   downgrade  2017-11-15
1     456         2017-03-01         2017-05-31      np.nan      np.nan
2     789         2017-02-01         2017-04-30   downgrade  2017-02-15
3     333         2017-08-01         2017-10-31      np.nan      np.nan
```

Please note the events can happen in any time range, and some are outside the `invoice` range (either before or after), or, there are multiple events within the `invoice` range. There may also be any number of other `user_id`'s that are either do not have any events, or are irrelevant to the main `df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We using `merge`+Boolean index +`drop_duplicates` +`combine_first`(Notice : New is the para I setting up here, you can drop it by using `drop('New',1)` at the end )

```
target=df.merge(event_df,on='user_id',how='left')
target['New']=(target.event_date>=target.first_invoice_date)&(target.event_date<=target.third_invoice_date)
df.set_index('user_id').\
   combine_first((target[target.New].drop_duplicates('user_id').\ 
      set_index('user_id')))
Out[531]: 
         New event_date event_type first_invoice_date third_invoice_date
user_id                                                                 
123      1.0 2017-11-15  downgrade         2017-10-01         2017-12-31
333      NaN        NaT        NaN         2017-08-01         2017-10-31
456      NaN        NaT        NaN         2017-03-01         2017-05-31
789      1.0 2017-02-15  downgrade         2017-02-01         2017-04-30
```

Comment: This is a really great idea, but `user_id` `333` does not have any events in `event_df`, but it appears in this process they are given the `downgrade` event from user `789`